# How to escape linebreak character while writing a csv with java/opencsv

Tags: java, export-to-csv, opencsv

I have a CSV file, which is saved as a Bean. One column has HTML tags including \n character. While reading with opencsv is not a problem, but when i write a new csv it actually creates a new line break/row. [image: CSV]

Here is what i have tried:

```
File file = new File(outDirectory, this.outputCSVName);

    try (
            Writer writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(file.toURI()));
    ) {
        StatefulBeanToCsv<Shopify> beanToCsv = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder(writer)
                .withQuotechar(CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER)
                .withApplyQuotesToAll(true)[![enter image description here][1]][1]
                .withEscapechar('\n')
                .withLineEnd("\n") // just to test
                .withSeparator(',')
                .build();

        beanToCsv.write(data);
        writer.close();

    } catch (CsvRequiredFieldEmptyException | IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (CsvDataTypeMismatchException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

and here is how it looks like in the arraylist:[image]

How can i write it as a string? Also how can i export it as a UTF-8 encoded file?

Comment: Maybe you want to change `.withQuotechar(CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER)`

Comment: @ScaryWombat you mean remove it?

Comment: *but when i write a new csv it actually creates a new line* What do you mean by that? *and here is how it looks like in the arraylist:* Not legible (and [Please never post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). They are not searchable, we cannot copy-paste... Always copy-paste the text and format it properly.)

Comment: Moreover, from what I can see of "Body", it looks like a string, and *not*  "a new csv"

Comment: @g00se it is a string, but somehow while writing the csv it is a line break

Comment: *.withEscapechar('\n')* doesn't make sense I don't *think* (I haven't used this method before). You wouldn't want an escape char to be a line feed. I would begin by deleting that line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggestion of @g00se made me remove the *.withEscapechar('\n')* and after that it worked fine. My final Export looks like this:

```
File file = new File(outDirectory, this.outputCSVName);

    try (
            Writer writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(file.toURI()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    ) {
        StatefulBeanToCsv<Shopify> beanToCsv = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder(writer)
                .withSeparator(',')
                .build();

        beanToCsv.write(data);
        writer.close();
        return "Export OK";
    } catch (CsvRequiredFieldEmptyException | IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (CsvDataTypeMismatchException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```